# How to expand a larger area in the content of an expander?

Tags: c#, wpf, blend, expander

I tried several times without finding how to expand a larger content in an expander without modifying the size of the header.

My collapsed expander with its linear gradient:
[image: Collpased expander]

**What I get**
[image: What I do NOT want]

or when I increase the size of my content
[image: What I do NOT want]

**What I want**
[image: What I WANT]

OR

[image: What I WANT]

I am working under Blend 4.
Is it possible to do that ? Do you have a trick ? Can I keep the linear gradient ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question. I deleted my previous answer, it's got nothing to do with what you're asking here

Comment: I do not think that you misunderstood because it was what I wanted. It's just that I have this "background issue" on top of that. Your solution was working great (using -20 instead of 20) but only with a uniform background because I need to apply two different backgrounds. Not only one for the expander but one for the header and one for the content. And as I am using a linear gradient, it is not very great. I do not continue the gradient but start a new one.